# AdomdRestrictionCollection - setting multiple values for restriction column

Tags: c#, ssas, data-warehouse, adomd.net

I would like to get all levels for some set of dimensions from MDSCHEMA_LEVELS.

Is it possible to set multiple values for restriction columns in AdomdRestrictionCollection? Or should I run the query for each dimension separately?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, one restriction (i. e. cube, level, ...) can only be used once in the restrictions. But you can omit a restriction completely, of course, i. e. not restricting on level to get all levels, or not restricting on dimensions to get data for all dimensions. It would then be decision to balance the effort of running many separate queries, or getting a few records you will ignore.